# OpenVDB 5.1.0 Hello World example link error on Mac

Tags: linker-errors, debug-symbols, dylib, unresolved-external, openvdb

I tried different ways to run the hello world example from the openvdb [cookbook](http://www.openvdb.org/documentation/doxygen/codeExamples.html#sCompilingHelloWorld) for the latest version 5.1.0. But I keep on getting `Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64` error on my MacBook pro (macOS High Sierra 10.13.4).

To narrow down the problem, I simplify the hello world example as:

```
//test.cpp
#include <openvdb/openvdb.h>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    openvdb::initialize();
}
```

To compile the code, I installed openvdb 5.1.0 using homebrew `brew install openvdb`. The command line I use to compile the code is (g++ version = 5.4.0):

```
g++ -g -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/Cellar/openvdb/5.1.0_1/include \
-I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/include \
-I /usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U4/include \
-L /usr/local/Cellar/openvdb/5.1.0_1/lib \
-L /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.67.0_1/lib \
-L /usr/local/Cellar/tbb/2018_U4/lib \
test.cpp -lopenvdb -ltbb -lHalf -lpthread
```

What I got is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"openvdb::v5_1::math::simplify(std::shared_ptr<openvdb::v5_1::math::AffineMap>)", referenced from:
  openvdb::v5_1::math::AffineMap::preRotate(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::AffineMap::preShear(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::AffineMap::postRotate(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::AffineMap::postShear(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::ScaleMap::preRotate(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::ScaleMap::preShear(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  openvdb::v5_1::math::ScaleMap::postRotate(double, openvdb::v5_1::math::Axis) const in ccBVTtHl.o
  ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems the `openvdb` lib does not have the function implementation included. Did I miss something?

I also tried to compile from openvdb git [v5.1.0](https://github.com/dreamworksanimation/openvdb/releases/tag/v5.1.0).Other dependent packages are installed via homebrew (Only blosc is pulled from c-blosc [git](https://github.com/Blosc/c-blosc)). However, the error is the same.

Anyone experience the same issue to make openvdb 5.1.0 run on Mac?

**Update**:

I try to use `nm` to figure out if the symbol inside test.o (use the same compile command without referring to any library) is inside `openvdb.dylib`. My target symbol here is `simplify`. The output is as below:

> $  nm -A test.o | grep simplify
>
> test.o:                  U
>   __ZN7openvdb4v5_14math8simplify**ESt10**shared_ptrINS1_9AffineMapEE
>
> $  nm -A libopenvdb.dylib | grep simplify
>
> libopenvdb.dylib: 0000000000027a2a T __ZN7openvdb4v5_14math8simplify**ENSt3__110**shared_ptrINS1_9AffineMapEE**E**
>
> $  nm -A git5.1.0/libopenvdb.dylib | grep simplify
>
> libopenvdb.dylib: 00000000000d56c0 T __ZN7openvdb8v5_**1abi34**math8simplify**EN5boost10**shared_ptrINS1_9AffineMapEE**E**

(I removed the path for better readability)

This is it! I have highlighted the three difference. I do not know the exact meaning of the highlighted part. My guess is that the shared_ptr in three file comes from different sources (C++x0,C++11,Boost)? But I compile test.o with Boost header included and c++11 turned on.

Any good suggestion for reasoning the difference?

Comment: Did you follow [these instructions](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/openvdb#macos)? I followed them without any issue.